# Автоскрывающийся popup уведомление

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, popup

На своем сайте я хочу сделать уведомление, если пользователь не зарегистрирован, то ему писало
"***Пожалуйста, войдите в аккаунт или зарегистрируйтесь***"
Но я очень плох в написании кода на js, так как я его совсем не учил и у меня просто нет времени на более плотное его изучение. В недрах моего разума родилось вот это

```
function showhidepopup() {
var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup");
popup.classList.toggle("show");
setTimeout(function () {
    popup.classList.toggle("hidepopup");
}, 5000);
setTimeout(function () {
    popup.classList.toggle("show");
    popup.classList.toggle("hidepopup")
}, 6500);}
```

Данная функция вызывается из другой функции через ajax

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/api/" + type + "/" + pk + "/" + action + "/",
    type: 'POST',
    data: {'obj': pk},

    success: function (json) {
        if (json.user_login === 0) {
            showhidepopup()
        } else {
            current.find("[data-count='" + action + "']").text(json.count);
            $('#bookmarks-user').text(json.user_mark)
            if ($(bookmarkheart).css('fill') == "rgb(255, 255, 255)") {
                $(bookmarkheart).css({fill: "#ffc96c"});
            } else {
                $(bookmarkheart).css({fill: "#ffffff"});
            }
        }

    }
});
```

Подскажите пожалуйста правильную реализацию автоскрывающегося popup уведомления, потому что это ужаснейший костыль

html

```
<span class="popuptext" id="myPopup">Пожалуйста, войдите в аккаунт или зарегистрируйтесь
    </span>
```

css

```
.popuptext::after {
    content: "";

}

.show {
    visibility: visible;
    -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s;
    animation: fadeIn 1s
}

.hidepopup {
    visibility: hidden;
    animation: fadeOut 1s
}

/* Add animation (fade in the popup) */
@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
    from {opacity: 0;}
    to {opacity: 1;}
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
    from {opacity: 0;}
    to {opacity:1 ;}
}

.fadeIn {
    animation-name: fadeIn;
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}
```

вот гифка как примерно это выглядит[image: gif]

Answer (score 0):

Не буду претендовать на полноценное решение, но вот как я обычно реализую подобное:

```js
class Notification {
  constructor(content) {
    this.content = content;
  }

  write(time = 10000) {
    const notification = document.createElement('div');
    notification.classList.add('notification');
    notification.textContent = this.content;
    notification.dataset.id = Math.random();
    document.querySelector('.notification-bar').appendChild(notification);
    setTimeout(() => {
      this._remove(notification.dataset.id);
    }, time);
  }

  _remove(id) {
    document.querySelector(`[data-id="${id}"]`).remove();
  }
}

const notification = new Notification('Войдите или зарегестрируйтесь..');
notification.write(2000);
```

```html
<div class="notification-bar"></div>
```

То-есть во время создания самого уведомления я присваиваю ему id и планирую через определенное время найти его по id и вызвать `.remove()`, т.е. удалить.